# how to prevent to start batches again if running the batch in spring batch?

Tags: spring-batch

I have two batch. I need processes thousand of transaction using batch.

**My case is:**

1. **If first batch stated, first batch will not start until the fist batch is completed**
2. **If first batch is completed , then start second batch.**
3. **If second batch started, second batch will not start until second batch is completed**

I are trying to launch two Spring Batch jobs sequentially.I have tried to below like.

Here is my batch configuration:

```
    public class RtgsJob {

            public Job createEft(){

                String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                id = "RTGS-STEP1-"+id;
                return new JobBuilder(id, jobRepository)
                        .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                        .start(step1())
                        .build();

            }


            public Job createEftTransaction(){
                String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                id = "RTGS-STEP2-"+id;
                return new JobBuilder(id, jobRepository)
                        .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                        .flow(step2())
                        .end()
                        .build();



            }

            private Step step1(){

                return new StepBuilder("step1", jobRepository)
                        .<mydata, mydata> chunk(10, transactionManager)
                        .reader(myReader)
                        .processor(myProcessor)
                        .writer(myWritter)
                        .build();
            }

            private Step step2(){

                return new StepBuilder("step2", jobRepository)
                        .<mydata, mydata> chunk(10, transactionManager)
                        .reader(myReader)
                        .processor(myProcessor)
                        .writer(myWritter)
                        .build();
            }

    }
```

I have run these batch using below code:

```
        JobExecution execution = null;
        JobExecution executionTransaction = null;

        if(execution == null) {
            // rtgs batch step1 {} execution {} Started: 
            try {
                execution = jobLauncher.run(eftJob.createEft(), new JobParameters());

               // rtgs batch {} Step1 existStatus: "+execution.getExitStatus()

            } catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException | JobRestartException | JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException |
                     JobParametersInvalidException ex) {
               
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                
            }



            if(execution.getExitStatus().getExitCode().equals("COMPLETED")){

                if(executionTransaction == null){
                    log.info(Constants.batchTag + "{} rtgs batch step2 {} executionTransaction {} Started: ");

                    try {
                        executionTransaction =   jobLauncher.run(eftJob.createEftTransaction(),new JobParameters());

                        //{} rtgs batch step2 {} executionTransaction {} Completed;

                    } catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException | JobRestartException | JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException |
                             JobParametersInvalidException ex) {

                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }catch (Exception ex) {

                        ex.printStackTrace();
                        

                    }
                }
            }


        }else{
            //{} rtgs batch step1 {} execution {} isRunning: ;
        }
```

If I request multiple request , both are running multiple times and make double transaction.

I need to run both batches synchronous. One batch is started it won't get any request. If both batch completed then start again.

**What is the wrong of my code?**

Please help me...